# How to set dynamic values to Docker

Tags: python, docker

I have this question, how can I dynamically change some values in `docker` once the image is built.

So basically I have this `Dockerfile` as below.

```
FROM python:3.7.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY server.py /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8083

# CMD ["python3", "-m",  "http.server", "8080"]
CMD ["python3", "./server.py"]
```

So currently the server is working as expected. But there is a variable in `server.py` that changing dynamically. Once the image is built, I can't change that variable as now the image is already built and that variable is always referring to the same value.

See `server.py` below:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import linearregression

PORT = 8083

file_path = "./prices.csv" # variable I need to change


predicted_values = linearregression.runModel(file_path)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    return "Predicted Values - " + str(predicted_values)

@app.route('/banuka')
def hi():
    return "Hi Jananath"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT)
```

As above, I have another `python` file called `linearregression.py` which has a method `runModel(file_path)` which accepts a parameter in a `String` format and returns some values.

This path has to be changed every time I upload a different file or change the content in the same file. But I can't do this since the **image is already built.**  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to define a variable with ENV in Dockerfile and start the container with '-e' option :

```
FROM python:3.7.7
...
ENV FILE_PATH=prices.csv
...
CMD ["python3", "./server.py"]
```

And in python code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import linearregression

PORT = 8083

file_path = os.environ['FILE_PATH'])
....
```

and run it as:

```
docker run -e FILE_PATH=/path/to/prices.csv ...
```

Comment: I will try this method and let you know. So according to this, even though the file has changed, or the content of the file has changed, the new values should be populated accordingly right?

Comment: The `file_path` becomes a variable that you can pass to the container on start.

Comment: So that means I have to stop the container and re-run it even if there is a change in that variable. Is there a way I can make it dynamic without starting a new container for every change?

Comment: The your application have to re-read the file or get the file name as a parameter of request

Comment: Can you elaborate on that more? And Is there a way I can use `docker volumes` to achieve this?